# Implementing Parcelable

Tags: android

I have implemented parcelable in many of my classes that only have String member variables. I am not sure how to do it for a class that has an ArrayList. What do I do in the constructor that takes in the source (Parcel)?

```
public class Schedule {

private ArrayList<Event> allEvents;

 public Schedule(Parcel source) {

    }

public Schedule(){
    allEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
}

//Getter
public ArrayList<Event> getAllEvents(){
    return allEvents;
}

public void addEvent(Event newEvent){
    allEvents.add(newEvent);
}

  public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(allEvents);
    }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Schedule> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<Schedule>() {

            @Override
            public Schedule createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new Schedule(source);
            }

            @Override
            public Schedule[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Schedule[size];
            }
        };
```

}

Comment: try [readArrayList(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readArrayList%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

Comment: Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071502/how-to-read-write-array-of-parcelable-objects-android/10072382#10072382) to see if it helps.

Comment: Try using http://www.parcelabler.com/