# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.hfad.myapp.MyObj[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, parcelable

I want to pass MyObj[ ] between activities.

I'm using an Intent and Parcelable to do so, but when I try to receive that data in Activity B I get the error:
"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.hfad.myapp.MyObj[ ]".

I saw that many people had problems with this but couldn't find a solution to my case.

This answer doesn't solve it [android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to... Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108986/android-os-parcelable-cannot-be-cast-to-error)

**MyObj class**

```
@Entity (tableName = "myobj")
public class MyObj implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String productName;
    private int numberOfproducts;

    protected MyObj (Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        productName = in.readString();
        numberOfproducts = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(productName);
        dest.writeInt(numberOfproducts);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyObj> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObj>() {
        @Override
        public MyObj createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObj(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObj[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObj[size];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public int getNumberOfproducts() {
        return numberOfproducts;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public MyObj(String productName, int numberOfproducts) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.numberOfproducts = numberOfproducts;

    }
}
```

**Activity A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("array", array);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity B**

```
//Here the error occurs
MyObj[] myArray = (MyObj[]) getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("array");
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Or should I use a different approach to pass data between Activities?

Comment: Did you check the answer to a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35109635/668148

Comment: Yes I did,  but It doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714927/pass-array-in-intent-using-parcelable

Comment: Thank you! It works