# Send string array from an activity in android

Tags: java, android

I have a quiz application I am working on whereby the questions, answers and options are embedded in the application with a timer. I also have two other activities: one for showing the user his current score and the other to review the answered questions once there is a timeout.
I intend to send the questions and answers the user has tried before the timer was over into my review activity for review. 
For example, since I have 10 questions in my application, and the user was able to try 5 out of them before the time elapsed, I need to get those 5 questions into my Review Activity for review.

**QuestionLibrary.Java**

```
// This file contains questions from QuestionBank
class QuestionLibrary {
    // array of questions
    private String mQuestions [] = {
          // Question goes here
   };
    // array of multiple choices for each question
    private String mChoices [][] = {
           // question choices goes here
    };

    // array of correct answers - in the same order as array of questions
private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {
         // answers appear here
};


    // method returns number of questions
    int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    // method returns question from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    String getQuestion(int a) {
        return mQuestions[a];
    }

    // method returns a single multiple choice item for question-based on array index,
    // based on number of multiple choice item in the list - 1, 2, 3 or 4 as an argument
    String getChoice(int index, int num) {
        return mChoices[index][num-1];
    }

    //  method returns correct answer for the question based on array index
    String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        return mCorrectAnswers[a];
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    TextView msingleQuestion;
    TextView mQuestion; //current question to answer
    TextView timer;
   MainActivity.CounterClass count_timer;   //countdown timer class
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0; // current question number
    private String mAnswer;  // correct answer for question in mQuestionView
    private int mquizNumber = 1;
    private long resume_timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // set textViews here
        // Setting countdown timer
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timer.setText("00:5:00");
        // start timer here
        count_timer = new MainActivity.CounterClass(300000, 1000);
        count_timer.start();
        updateQuizNumber(mquizNumber);

    }

    private void updateQuizNumber(int mquizNumber) {
        msingleQuestion.setText("" + mquizNumber+"/"+mQuestionLibrary.getLength());
    }


    private void updateQuestion() {
        // check if we are not outside array bounds for questions
        if(mQuestionNumber<mQuestionLibrary.getLength() ){
            // set text for hint and click_me
            mClickMe.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getTextHint(mQuestionNumber));
            // set the text for new question, and new 4 alternative to answer on four buttons
            mQuestion.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            button1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));
            button2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));
            button3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));
            button4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(BeginnerActivity.this, "That was the last question!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        //all logic for all answers buttons in one method

        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            // once user answer the question, we move on to the next one, if any
                    updateQuestion();
                    mquizNumber++;
                    updateQuizNumber(mquizNumber);
                }

            }, 1000);


        } else {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    count_timer.cancel();
                }

            }, 1000);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        //resume timer when user comes back to the app
        count_timer = new BeginnerActivity.CounterClass(resume_timer, 1000);
        count_timer.start();
        super.onRestart();
    }
}
```

How do I get the tried questions from my Main Activity into another Activity for a proper review?

Comment: Implement Parcelable interface in QuestionLibrary and put it in intent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071502/read-writing-arrays-of-parcelable-objects

Comment: would this help me retrieve the exact questions the user attempted before the timer elapsed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to send String array via intent

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, stringArrayReference);
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

In order to get the String array in other Activity you can use below code

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for this. but how do i get the stringArrayReference? parcelable interface?

Comment: As in your code I can see string array having reference name as mQuestions , use that reference or other string array reference

Comment: but this would get all the questions from the library. i just want to retrieve the questions the user has attempted before the timer elapsed.

Comment: would this help me retrieve the exact questions the user attempted before the timer elapsed?