# Android - android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I've been working on a assignment that revolves around creating a smaller app for the game Thirty - a variant of Yatzy. Getting some error messages though with my parcelables. The error is according to the stacktrace somewhere in the class GameHandler or GameRound, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Code and stack trace below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class GameHandler implements Parcelable {
    private int round = 0;

    private GameRound[] rounds = new GameRound[]{
            new GameRound(0),
            new GameRound(1),
            new GameRound(2),
            new GameRound(3),
            new GameRound(4),
            new GameRound(5),
            new GameRound(6),
            new GameRound(7),
            new GameRound(8),
            new GameRound(9)
    };
    public GameHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the round
     */
    public GameRound[] getRounds() {
        return rounds;
    }

    /**
     * Return the round number
     */
    public int getRoundNbr() {
        return round;
    }


    /**
     * Increases the round number
     */
    public void incRound() {
        round += 1;
    }

    /**
     * Return the current round
     */
    public GameRound getCurrentRound() {
        return rounds[round];
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Writes to parcel
     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.round);
        dest.writeTypedArray(this.rounds, flags);
    }


    /**
     * Gets values from Parcelable
     */
    protected GameHandler(Parcel in) {
        this.round = in.readInt();
        this.rounds = in.createTypedArray(GameRound.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<GameHandler> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GameHandler>() {
        @Override
        public GameHandler createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new GameHandler(source);
        }

        @Override
        public GameHandler[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GameHandler[size];
        }
    };
}
```

```
public class GameRound implements Parcelable {
    private int round;
    private String choice;
    private int throwNbr;
    private int score;
    private Die[] dice;
    private int[] diceStates;

    public GameRound(int roundNumber) {
        round = roundNumber;
        choice = null;
        throwNbr = 1;
        dice = new Die[]{
                new Die(0),
                new Die(1),
                new Die(2),
                new Die(3),
                new Die(4),
                new Die(5)
        };
    }


    /**
     * Return the choice for the current round
     */

    public String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public void setChoice(String string) {
        choice = string;
    }

    /**
     * Return the round
     */
    public int getRoundNbr() {
        return round;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the dice
     */
    public Die[] getDice() {
        return dice;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the score to the value of die
     */
    public void setScore(int value) {
        score = value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the score
     */
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current throw number
     */
    public int getThrowNbr() {
        return throwNbr;
    }

    /**
     * Increases the number of throws
     */
    public void incThrow() {
        throwNbr += 1;
    }


    /**
     * Calculates the score if the option "Low" has been chosen and stores the score in the variable "score"
     */
    public void Low(ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> values) {
        int score = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Die> solution : values) {
            for (Die die : solution) {
                if (die.getState() <= 3) {
                    score += die.getState();
                }
            }
        }
        setScore(score);
        setChoice("Low");
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the score for all the different options except "Low".
     * Recursively iterates through all the different possible solutions and returns
     * option - the desired value for score calculation,
     * ArrayList<Die> dice - a list with Die-objects,
     * ArrayList<Die> previous - a list with Die-objects
     *
     * @return ArrayList<ArrayList < Die>> Containing one of the solutions with the highest number of combinations of values that equals the desired value.
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> calculateScore(int option, ArrayList<Die> dice, ArrayList<Die> previous) {
        if (dice.size() == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>>();
        } else {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>>> subtrees = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Die d : dice) {
                ArrayList<Die> newDice = new ArrayList<Die>();

                for (Die d2 : dice) {
                    if (d2 != d) {
                        newDice.add(d2);
                    }
                }

                if (d.getState() == option) {

                    ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> recursiveSolutions = calculateScore(option, newDice, new ArrayList<Die>());
                    recursiveSolutions.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(d)));
                    subtrees.add(recursiveSolutions);
                } else if ((d.getState() + Die.Sum(previous)) == option) {

                    ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> recursiveSolutions = calculateScore(option, newDice, new ArrayList<Die>());

                    ArrayList<Die> solution = new ArrayList<>(previous);

                    solution.add(d);

                    recursiveSolutions.add(solution);

                    subtrees.add(recursiveSolutions);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Die> newPrevious = new ArrayList<>(previous);
                    newPrevious.add(d);
                    subtrees.add(calculateScore(option, newDice, newPrevious));
                }
            }

            ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> solution = new ArrayList<>();

            int max = 0;

            for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> subtree : subtrees) {

                if (subtree.size() > max) {
                    max = subtree.size();
                    solution = subtree;
                }
            }

            setChoice(Integer.toString(option));
            saveScore(solution);
            return solution;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the score in the Round-objects score variable
     */
    public void saveScore(ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> result) {
        int score = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Die> solution : result) {
            for (Die die : solution) {
                score += die.getState();
            }
        }
        setScore(score);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Writes to parcel
     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.choice);
        dest.writeInt(this.throwNbr);
        dest.writeInt(this.score);
        dest.writeInt(this.round);
        dest.writeTypedArray(this.dice, flags);
        dest.writeIntArray(this.diceStates);
    }

    /**
     * Gets values from Parcelable
     */
    protected GameRound(Parcel in) {
        this.choice = in.readString();
        this.throwNbr = in.readInt();
        this.score = in.readInt();
        this.round = in.readInt();
        this.dice = (Die[]) in.readArray(Die.class.getClassLoader());
        this.diceStates = in.createIntArray();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<GameRound> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GameRound>() {
        @Override
        public GameRound createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new GameRound(source);
        }

        @Override
        public GameRound[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GameRound[size];
        }
    };
}
```

```
2019-07-29 09:05:17.252 5192-5192/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.thirtygame, PID: 5192
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thirtygame/com.example.thirtygame.MainActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2831)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2757)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2660)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayInternal(Parcel.java:3100)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArray(Parcel.java:2327)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound.<init>(GameRound.java:208)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound$1.createFromParcel(GameRound.java:215)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound$1.createFromParcel(GameRound.java:212)
    at android.os.Parcel.readTypedObject(Parcel.java:2606)
    at android.os.Parcel.createTypedArray(Parcel.java:2568)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler.<init>(GameHandler.java:77)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler$1.createFromParcel(GameHandler.java:83)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler$1.createFromParcel(GameHandler.java:80)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2766)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2660)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3029)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.getBoolean(BaseBundle.java:894)
    at android.app.Activity.restoreHasCurrentPermissionRequest(Activity.java:7442)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7132)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thirtygame/com.example.thirtygame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.thirtygame.Die[]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.thirtygame.Die[]
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound.<init>(GameRound.java:208)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound$1.createFromParcel(GameRound.java:215)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameRound$1.createFromParcel(GameRound.java:212)
    at android.os.Parcel.readTypedObject(Parcel.java:2606)
    at android.os.Parcel.createTypedArray(Parcel.java:2568)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler.<init>(GameHandler.java:77)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler$1.createFromParcel(GameHandler.java:83)
    at com.example.thirtygame.GameHandler$1.createFromParcel(GameHandler.java:80)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2766)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2660)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3029)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.getBoolean(BaseBundle.java:894)
    at android.app.Activity.restoreHasCurrentPermissionRequest(Activity.java:7442)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7132)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Die class as requested:

```
    public class Die implements Parcelable {
private int ID;
private int State;
private boolean isSelected;

public Die(int ID) {
    this.State = 0;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.isSelected = false;
}

/**
 * Returns ID of die
 */
public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

/**
 * Sets die to selected
 */
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}

/**
 * Returns true if die is selected, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

/**
 * Sets the state of die
 */
public void setState(int state) {
    State = state;
}

/**
 * Returns the state of die
 */
public int getState() {
    return State;
}

/**
 * Return the sum of the states of the dice
 */
public static int Sum(ArrayList<Die> dice)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (Die die:dice) {
        sum += die.getState();
    }
    return sum;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Writes values to Parcelable
 */
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.ID);
    dest.writeInt(this.State);
    dest.writeByte(this.isSelected ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
}

/**
 * Gets values from Parcelable
 */
protected Die(Parcel in) {
    this.ID = in.readInt();
    this.State = in.readInt();
    this.isSelected = in.readByte() != 0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Die> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Die>() {
    @Override
    public Die createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Die(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Die[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Die[size];
    }
};
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Spinner scoreSelector;
private Button throwBttn;
private ImageButton[] imgbttns = new ImageButton[6];
private Random random = new Random();
public static GameHandler gh = new GameHandler();
private ArrayList<Integer> values;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private int randomNbr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView round = findViewById(R.id.round);
    scoreSelector = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    throwBttn = findViewById(R.id.throw_button);

    String[] scoreList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.score_array);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(scoreList)));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    scoreSelector.setAdapter(adapter);

    throwBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            throwDice();
        }
    });

    ImageButton die1 = findViewById(R.id.die1);
    ImageButton die2 = findViewById(R.id.die2);
    ImageButton die3 = findViewById(R.id.die3);
    ImageButton die4 = findViewById(R.id.die4);
    ImageButton die5 = findViewById(R.id.die5);
    ImageButton die6 = findViewById(R.id.die6);

    imgbttns[0] = die1;
    imgbttns[1] = die2;
    imgbttns[2] = die3;
    imgbttns[3] = die4;
    imgbttns[4] = die5;
    imgbttns[5] = die6;


    round.setText("Round " + String.valueOf(gh.getRoundNbr() + 1));

    setListenerDice();


    disableGameField();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        gh = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Gamehandler");

        loadPrevious();

        enableGameField();
    } else {
        throwBttn.setText("First throw");
    }
}


/**
 * Loads the dice values (Die-object) and sets the ImageButton for each die to the corresponding image.
 */

private void loadPrevious() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imgbttns.length; i++) {
        Die die = gh.getRounds()[gh.getRoundNbr()].getDice()[i];
        int diceValue = die.getState();
        if (die.isSelected()) {
            setGrey(die, diceValue);
        } else {
           setWhite(die, diceValue);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Puts OnClickListener on the dice i.e. on the ImageButtons in imgbttns
 */
private void setListenerDice() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imgbttns.length; i++) {
        imgbttns[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageButton bttn = (ImageButton) v;
                int index = Arrays.asList(imgbttns).indexOf(v);
                Die die = gh.getRounds()[gh.getRoundNbr()].getDice()[index];
                int diceValue = die.getState();
                if (die.isSelected()) {
                    die.setSelected(false);
                    setWhite(die, diceValue);
                } else {
                    die.setSelected(true);
                    setGrey(die, diceValue);
                }
                v.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Disables all ImageButton-instances in imgbttns
 */
private void disableGameField() {
    for (ImageButton bttn : imgbttns) {
        bttn.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Enables all ImageButton-instances in imgbttns
 */
private void enableGameField() {
    for (ImageButton bttn : imgbttns) {
        bttn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Called on every click on First Throw/Throw/Score-button.
 * Checks that the number of throws in the current round.
 * If less than 4 throws - new values for the dice are generated and a new gameround is shown via DrawDice().
 * If 4 throws - the text on the throw-button is changed to Score/Next Round
 * Else - the gameround is reset: the dice show the value 1 and are no longer clickable and the text on the throw-button is set to First throw.
 */
private void throwDice() {
    throwBttn.setText("Throw");
    enableGameField();

    // If less than 4 throws
    if (gh.getCurrentRound().getThrowNbr() <= 4) {

        gh.getCurrentRound().incThrow();

        drawDice();

        if ((gh.getCurrentRound().getThrowNbr() == 4)) {
            throwBttn.setText("Score/Next Round");
            gh.getCurrentRound().incThrow();
        }
    }

    // Reset the dice and change the text of the Throw-button (and start a new round)
    else {
        resetDice();
        throwBttn.setText("First throw");
        disableGameField();
    }
}

/**
 * Generates new random values for each Die-object associated with the current round and changes the image
 * associated with the corresponding imgbttn-object
 */
public void drawDice() {
    for (Die die : gh.getRounds()[gh.getRoundNbr()].getDice()) {
        randomNbr = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (!die.isSelected()) {
            die.setState(randomNbr);
            setWhite(die, randomNbr);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Gets the score and resets the game. Also removes the chosen scoring option from the
 * spinner as each can only be chosen once during a game.
 */
public void resetDice() {

    ArrayList<Die> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(gh.getCurrentRound().getDice()));
    String score_val = scoreSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

    switch (score_val) {
        case "Low":
            score(1, values);
            break;
        case "4":
            score(4, values);
            break;
        case "5":
            score(5, values);
            break;
        case "6":
            score(6, values);
            break;
        case "7":
            score(7, values);
            break;
        case "8":
            score(8, values);
            break;
        case "9":
            score(9, values);
            break;
        case "10":
            score(10, values);
            break;
        case "11":
            score(11, values);
            break;
        case "12":
            score(12, values);
            break;
    }

    //If round is below 9, i.e less than 10 rounds has been played
    if (gh.getRoundNbr() < 9) {
        gh.incRound();
        final TextView textViewToChange = findViewById(R.id.round);
        textViewToChange.setText(
                "Round " + String.valueOf(gh.getRoundNbr() + 1));

        for (Die die : gh.getRounds()[gh.getRoundNbr()].getDice()) {
            die.setSelected(false);
            int diceVal = die.getState();
            die.setSelected(false);
            die.setState(1);
            imgbttns[die.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white1);
        }

        // Show result if 9th round
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    adapter.remove((String) scoreSelector.getSelectedItem());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

/**
 * Sends the value from each die to score calculating
 * If the alternative "Low" is marked, then the score is calculated in the method Low
 */
private void score(int option, ArrayList<Die> values) {
    if (option == 1) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> newVals = new ArrayList<>();
        newVals.add(values);
        gh.getRounds()[gh.getRoundNbr()].Low(newVals);
    } else {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> results = gh.getCurrentRound().calculateScore(option, values, new ArrayList<Die>());
    }

}

/*
* Private help methods to use in the methods above to set up the images.
*/

private void setGrey(Die d, int value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey1);
            break;
        case 2:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey2);
            break;
        case 3:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey3);
            break;
        case 4:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey4);
            break;
        case 5:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey5);
            break;
        case 6:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.grey6);
            break;
    }

}

private void setWhite(Die d, int value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white1);
            break;
        case 2:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white2);
            break;
        case 3:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white3);
            break;
        case 4:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white4);
            break;
        case 5:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white5);
            break;
        case 6:
            imgbttns[d.getID()].setImageResource(R.drawable.white6);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    this.finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("Gamehandler", gh);
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781119/1042124

Comment: The error based on your log is triggered inside MainActivity class due to a wrong cast of Die[] object. Find that line.

Comment: Added my MainActivity above, can't for the world of it find the problem. Been scrutinizing the code all day

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code, but make sure you `Die` class also implements Parcelable

Comment: Posting the Die class below - it does implement Parcelable yet something goes wrong.

Comment: @jd15 You do not post questions as an answer. Kindly add your code block to your initial question rather than as an answer.

Comment: @giddyNaya oh sorry, will do! New here.

Comment: You're highly welcome! And no need for apologize we don't train snakes here.